# Creating temp column upon logic

Tags: sql

How can I create a temp (empty) column in which values will be inserted upon logic:

```
SELECT ..., *temp_col*

FROM *table*

IF *table.column_1* is not null, THEN *temp_col=table.column_1*

else temp_col=table.column_2
```

Note: Colume_1 is a CLOB field which will be transformed to TEXT.
someone advised me to use the EXIST condition.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you use the `CASE` expression or the `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT ...,
       COALESCE(table.column_1, table.column_2) as temp_col
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Case` :

```
SELECT ...,
       temp_col= CASE WHEN table.column_1 is not nul THEN table.column_1
       ELSE
       table.column_2 END
FROM table;
```